# Docker driver "aufs" failed to remove root filesystem - no such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, docker

Hello I have problem with remove dead docker containers:

```
root @ bespokeworktoptool3 /root ### docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

root @ server /root ### docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
79ae723f9f1c        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2   "/bin/bash bin/es-..."   3 weeks ago         Dead                                    elasticsearch
a31ce7855461        mobz/elasticsearch-head:5                             "/bin/sh -c 'grunt..."   3 weeks ago         Dead                                    elasticsearch_head
f2b27b8bc383        teamzeus/remote-syslog:0.19                           "/bin/sh -c 'watch..."   2 months ago        Dead                                    remote_syslog

root @ server /root ### docker rm f2b27b8bc383
Error response from daemon: driver "aufs" failed to remove root filesystem for f2b27b8bc383260847d5445045bca41245f0f99758b8c821b8940e7fe917831d: no such file or directory
```

I tried also restart docker and server but it don't resolve it:

```
Aug  9 21:52:42 server dockerd[3609]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:42.079905794+01:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
Aug  9 21:52:42 server dockerd[3609]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:42.14990583+01:00" level=info msg="stopping containerd after receiving terminated"
Aug  9 21:52:43 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:43.211939467+01:00" level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]"
Aug  9 21:52:43 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:43.212128824+01:00" level=warning msg="[!] DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting --tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING [!]"
Aug  9 21:52:43 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:43.213296124+01:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 3787"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.220498875+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.227799375+01:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.227983072+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup memory limit"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.228026980+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs period"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.228038239+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup cfs quotas"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.228058458+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.228067656+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.228160487+01:00" level=warning msg="mountpoint for pids not found"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.228417188+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.671816196+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.817138265+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.821916750+01:00" level=warning msg="Couldn't run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-aufs-union682049774: exec: \"auplink\": executable file not found in $PATH"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server kernel: [ 2293.474354] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[3798]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.879395591+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.879443798+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=02c1d87 graphdriver=aufs version=17.06.0-ce
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.890228004+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.893844194+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on 127.0.0.1:2376"
Aug  9 21:52:44 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:52:44.893993977+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on 172.30.100.33:2376"
Aug  9 21:53:28 server dockerd[3775]: time="2017-08-09T21:53:28.716242215+01:00" level=error msg="Error removing mounted layer f2b27b8bc383260847d5445045bca41245f0f99758b8c821b8940e7fe917831d: no such file or directory"
```

Do you anybody know how resolve it?